# Python Flask redirect- UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, flask, return

Weirdly, this code seemed to be working yesterday now I'm getting a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment` error when I run the app. From what I can see, the code clearly defines the query variable before the redirect takes place. I'm a bit stumped.

Can anyone see any issues?

```
####Index Page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
        exception = ""
        try:
            connectToDB()
        except:
            exception = 'Failure to connect to db'

        form = StaffNames()
        ranumber = form.ranumber.data
        if not exception:
                if form.validate_on_submit():
                        query = {
                                'staff': dict(staff_choices).get(form.staff.data),
                                'ranumber': form.ranumber.data,
                                'rai_number' : columnsearch(ranumber)["rai_number"],
                                'carrier_format' : columnsearch(ranumber)["carrier_format"],
                                'physical_location' : columnsearch(ranumber)["physical_location"],
                                'brand_title' : columnsearch(ranumber)["brand_title"],
                                'recording_artist' : columnsearch(ranumber)["recording_artist"],
                                'producer' : columnsearch(ranumber)["producer"],
                                'session' : columnsearch(ranumber)["session"],
                                'tx_date' : columnsearch(ranumber)["tx_date"],
                                }
                return redirect(url_for('results', **query))

        return render_template(
            'index.html', title='Search Page', exception=exception, form=form
        )
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Check for a mix of tabs and spaces.

Comment: ok, I've amended that, I still cant load the index page though.

Comment: Now the indentation is fixed it is pretty clear; `query` is not defined when `if form.validate_on_submit()` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case if `form.validate_on_submit()` evaluates to `False`, `query` is not defined.

Check your indentation!

Comment: ok, cheers for the response. The thing is 'form.validate_on_submit()' relates to a [DataRequired()]) validator in the form. The page needs to load before it can be assessed whether or not the user has input any data. I can't see how it can evaluate to false before anyone's had a chance to input data into the form and hit submit.

Comment: @bms9nmh: yet that is what happens. Debug the data posted. And at the very least indent that `return` statement properly.

Comment: Ah yes...sorry my return statement was not indented correctly. Thanks for your help guys.